# Rows to Columns in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get set of mail Ids  but in my Query this is not getting parsed properly as single row.Please hlep me to solve this.

```
    SELECT LISTAGG ( EMAIL) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL) EMAIL1 FROM USER  
WHERE ID IN (107) GROUP BY EMAIL
```

Current Output :

```
abdul@eetmx.com
joseph@eetmx.com
ranjith@eetmx.com
```

Expected Output :

```
abdul@eetmx.com,joseph@eetmx.com,ranjith@eetmx.com
```

Comment: Because you have `GROUP BY EMAIL` each Email is a group - hence you get a separate row for each.  You must ask yourself the question what does the list of EMails apply to ?  A Department ? A Salary ....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're grouping on `EMAIL`which is why they end up on different rows. Try grouping by `ID` instead like:

```
SELECT LISTAGG ( EMAIL, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL) EMAIL1 
FROM USER
WHERE ID IN (107) 
GROUP BY ID
```

For a working example see this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b200/1).

On a side note `USER`is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm) in both ANSI and Oracle SQL and should not be used as a table name.